# Preventing USER root in Dockerfile (or at least being able to spot it)

Tags: docker

We want to provide a base image (base OS + Java JRE) to developers. Since this is for a paranoid organization we want to make sure that the container will always run with the application id (a.k.a. "app"). Putting a `USER app` at the end of the Dockerfile for the base image is not enough since a Dockerfile for a derived image can use `USER root`. Is there either:

- a way to prevent using the `USER root` in derived images, or, failing this
- a watertight way to check an image for this (is searching the history for `USER [root]` statements enough? Or could this be concealed in some way (multistage-image...)).

Answer (score 0):

If you give users access to the Docker API without additional measures, such as "authorization" ("authz") plugins, those users effectively have *root* permissions on the host where the Docker daemon runs; https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/security/#docker-daemon-attack-surface.

You can configure the daemon to use user namespaces; https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/. When using user-namespaces, users inside the container are "remapped" to unprivileged users on the host, so `root` inside a container is a non-privileged user outside of the container.

There are limitations when running with user-namespaces enabled, for example, when bind mounting directories from the host, the container's process may not be able to access/write to those files (depending on configuration); this is by design, and part of the protection that user-namespaces provide, but may be an issue, depending on your situation.